# Sequelize afterValidate hook called twice when updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in a Node backend to access a MySQL database and I realized that, depending on how you update an object, the `afterValidate` hook is called once or twice. I'll explain it better with an example:

We have a `Shop` entity defined by the following Sequelize model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Shop = sequelize.define('Shop', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    address: DataTypes.STRING      
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
        afterValidate: (shop, options) => {
          shop.name += '_HOOKED!';   // Just for testing
        }
      }
  });
};
```

I've added a couple of shops using `db.Shop.create()` that have id 1 and 2. Now, I'm trying these 2 options that Sequelize provides to update a shop object:

**Option 1**

```
db.Shop.update({ name: 'Coffee Shop TEST' }, 
{ where: { id: shop.id } }).then((data) => {
  console.log("All good!!");
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("No good: ", error);
});
```

**Option 2**

```
db.Shop.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } }).then((shop) => {
  shop.update({ name: 'Coffee Shop TEST' }).then((data) => {
    console.log("All good!!: ");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("No good: ", error);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error al actualizar: ", error);
});
```

If I use the first option, the shop is updated correctly and the `afterValidate` hook is called once, so the name now is: `Coffee Shop TEST_HOOKED!`.

However, if I use the second option, the hook is called twice so the name is set incorrectly to `Coffee Shop TEST_HOOKED!_HOOKED!`.

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you have a `beforeUpdate` hook that is modifying data in any way?

Comment: Hi! No, I only have the `afterValidate` hook. I think that there are 2 possible reasons for this behaviour: 1. The `Shop` model has a `hasMany` and a `belongsToMany` relationships (I didn't show it in the example because I thought it wasn't relevant) and perhaps it does some extra processing that leads to a second validation. 2. The sequelize version I use is 5.21.2 and I'm almost sure that this wasn't happening before. I'll do some tests and I'll post an update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late but for anyone who comes across this problem, here is the solution:

You can set `options.validate = false` in the *beforeUpdate* hook in your model.

For some reason, Sequelize runs the *afterValidate* hook twice when updating objects...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update an object that doesn't have any associations with other models and I got the same result: option 1 calls `afterValidate` hook once and option 2 calls it twice. Also, I tried to go back to sequelize version 5.1.0 and nothing changed.

So, it seems that sequelize works this way for whatever reason. I'll keep in mind that, if I want to update an object that has hooks on it, I'll use the code in option 1 to avoid problems like hashing the password twice.

Cheers,